# Reading from multiple bluetooth Socket in Android (Single Thread)

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I have multiple Bluetooth Sockets, and i need to read from each of them without being blocked.

I could launch a new Thread for each socket but i would prefer having only one thread since i can have a lot of connected sockets to manage, and launching a lot of threads would impact performances (correct me if i'm wrong)

Is there an epoll / select equivalent in Java / Android API that i could use ?

Thanks a million,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since Bluetooth can handle 7 devices at most, launching 7 Threads has no real impact on performances, and is probably much simpler than using a multiplexer.

I will use multiple threads then.